# Is there a way of sending form values without inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Let say that I have the form below:

```
<form action="sendMessage.php" method="post">
    <label>Subject</label><input type="text"></input>
    <label>Message</label><input type="text"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

How can I send an another value like topic(which is pre-defined) without creating an another element for that? Is it possible or do I have to make input element and style it with `display: none;`

The answer can contain html, javascript or jquery code.

Comment: use jquery to create hidden input elements inside the form, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use a hidden input element:

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "topic" value = "something" />
```

Comment: This is pretty straight forward, nice!

Comment: On an aside, if you're looking to pass values from the server for client-side use only (eg. JS), you can avoid creating form input elements by using an `i` element with `data-*` attributes, for eg. `<i id="tracking-id" data-value="UA-XXXXX-X"></i>`. You can `display: none` this element, but it shouldn't affect the UI.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've usually seen this done is: `<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="myValue" />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="topic" value="My Topic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_value' value='hidden' />
```

In you form you will either have access to `$_GET['hidden_value']` or `$_POST['hidden_value']` depending on your form method. The value of the variable will be `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally use JQuery's ajax method when submitting your form:

```
<form action="process_form">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>

<script>
$(form).submit(function(){
    var formdata = $(this).serialize()+"&var1=12&var2=24";

    $.ajax(function(){
        url: 'http://example.com/process_form'
        data: formdata,
        success: function(data){

            // do something nice here

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This simply adds your form variables to the form data url string