# How do I get a non-input element to send data with a form (POST request)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, post

I have an HTML form that sends a `POST` request. Not all of the data that needs to be sent in the `POST` request is entered with `input` elements, though. I have a numerical value that I want to send along with the rest of the `POST` data when a user submits the form. How do I do that (without using AJAX)?

Comment: Use a hidden element, and add the value.

Comment: I had the same question. I think this question shouldn't have been downvoted.

Comment: I don't understand why it has been downvoted either. There is a week between when the question was asked and its last edit. Maybe it was less legible before.

Comment: Well anyway it seems to be effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612844/is-there-a-way-of-sending-form-values-without-inputs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) which you change its value according to what you did with your sliders.

```
<input type="hidden" id="slider_input" name="slider" value="" />
```

And then later in your JS / jQuery

```
$('.slider').change(function(){
    $('#slider_input').val(/* what you want */);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You have two options:

1. Use a hidden `<input />`, and set the value when the slider values are changed.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="range" />
   ```
2. Use a Range input, with `<input type="range" />`.

   ```
   <input type="range" name="range" />
   ```

Comment: `type="range"`: +1 for semantics, -0.1 for slightly worse browser support. :)

Comment: @gcampbell Ha ha ha... I am not a part of WHATWG or Chrome. :(